# css fixed footer moves to middle of screen with screen rotation

Tags: android, ios, css, asp.net

Working on a website using asp and vb.net, javascript, and heavy css.
I used a fixed footer across the bottom of the screen.

Works fine on laptops and pc's, even surfaces and ipads.

However, when viewed on an iPhone, Android phone, or kindle, the fixed footer starts at the bottom correctly, but if the phone is turned horizontally, the footer, while it initially appears correctly at the bottom, doesn't stay at the bottom as the user scrolls down through content.  is this a phone issue?  if so, is there some way to redefine the CSS for those user agents to compensate so that the footer does actually stay locked to the bottom of the screen, and not just at the height it starts at?

```
.FooterBanner {

width: 1966px;
position:absolute;
bottom:120px;
height:47px;
left: 0px;

}


.FooterHome
{
background-image: url('/Images/HeaderBg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
padding: 5px 0px 22px 10px;
width:99%;
min-width:500px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
height:50px;
z-index:900;
margin:auto;
vertical-align:top;

}
```

Comment: Could you show us the css?

Comment: added css to question, but as you can see... not really much too it... position fixed and possibly the margin auto? would be the only things that actually would affect placement on the screen; possibly z index, but that's the only piece that's at 900, so it's not fitting _with_ anything...